# Hi there, looking for prior art searchers who would be open to try a new non-commercial prior art search tool and share their feedback!

Tags: prior-art

Before I tell more about the tool, it's developed by my colleagues, my role is to collect feedback from beta users and share it with the development team to improve the tool. Also, the tool is a work in progress. Thanks for your time and feedback.

Here is how this tool is different from state-of-the-art:

1. It shows only the most relevant top 10 prior art search results.
2. It takes the query in plain English and not a complex boolean string.
3. It shows query element mapping with the relevant text from the prior art document, thus saving you time from sifting through prior art results, something like:

[image]

You can try it out at https://projectpq.ai

**The poster is a co-developer of this tool which is a work in progress.**

Comment: Tried the text of claim 1 of an application that was the subject of a recent question. There was no commonality between the "top ten" and the three references cited in the final OA.   It took longer to compare the references since you do not list the inventor. Names stick in the mind easier than seven digit numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I don't believe that SE has a PM facility and there is no contact info in your profile.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeWhite, Thanks for your time in trying out the tool and sharing the feedback. Means a lot. PQAI is still a work in progress and we are happy to receive honest feedback from the beta users. I understand the top 10 results didn't include the top 3 references. But were the top 10 results relevant?

Comment: Aaah, I am new to SE and hence did not know that it does not have PM facility. Hence for the reference of the other searchers, I am sharing the link of the search engine here: https://projectpq.ai

Comment: This is a question and answer site, not a forum. If you could try to phrase your entry as an objective question it would help. Otherwise it looks a bit like spam. Also please explicitly state your affiliation with the website you are referencing.

Comment: I'll play with it some more, but my initial impression is it doesn't work very well. 10 top hits is far too few. Tested with terms relating to my patents fails to find any of my patents. You should be able to select hits that are relevant and have it refine the search. As it is, I can't see my using it.

Comment: Very strange searching behavior. I was searching on PCR methods and then used one of the canned searches for a coffee maker. I got PCR hits in the results. As far as I can tell it remembers past searches as part of the current search which is really a bad idea.

Comment: I put "toaster with sensing color of toast" into pqai and to google patents. PQAI returned things that were relevant, google patents didn't - at least on the first page.

Comment: last comment - I got a biopsy today with a cylindrical punch. My Dr. wondered if one with an elliptical shape might be novel and easier to suture. I "put skin punch biopsy oval dermal elliptical" into PQAI and google patents. Google patents first page had three that fit the bill, the best from KR.  Zero on PQAI.

Comment: Hi @EricS my colleagues have developed the tool, and it's still a work under progress. My role is to get users to try the tool, collect feedback and share with my team so that they can improve the searching capability as well as user experience. I really appreciate that you took time out to try the tool. I shall pass the feedback to the development team. Our development team is continuously training the AI engine to perform better. Beta users like you are a great help. Your feedback matters to us. Also the tool is going to be open source to invite finest minds for collaboration.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeWhite wish you super fast recovery. Thanks for your time to try out PQAI. I shall pass on your feedback to the development team.

Comment: Hi @GeorgeWhite, Also regarding the inventor name we have listing of first inventor's last name on our to-do list.

Comment: Adita, please add to your question your affiliation to PQAI. I’m afraid I really insist on this. Otherwise we may need to close the question.

Comment: Sure @EricS I have added my association in the question itself. Thanks

Comment: 10 results are definitely not enough. Prior art searches can go through thousands of results. And a date filter would be very useful. Searches are far less important for new inventions than for existing patents/applications.

Answer (score 1):

My initial impression is that the tool is not at present very useful. The main issue I see is that previous queries seem to affect future queries. For instance look at this result:

[image]

It is pretty clear that the first and second hit has nothing whatsoever to do with coffee makers. In fact it looks like it is ignoring the sample query altogether as none of the results are relevant. This must be a bug. I'm using Safari as a browser on MacOS.

**Update: The bug seems to be cookie related. Once I deleted the cookies for PQAI, the searching seems to be fixed.**

Another issue I have is that only 10 results is too few. This should be adjustable by a user specified parameter.

Perhaps the most annoying feature is that it doesn't like my own patents. I've put search queries targeted to my own patents and it never identifies any of my own even though they are exactly related. I even copied the entire first claim of one of my more cited patents and it didn't identify my patent within the first 10 hits.

Comment: Hi @EricS, As an expert prior art searcher the feeling that 10 results are not enough is well understood. However, out of 10 if you find any results relevant, you can click on "Find Similar" button and PQAI shall try to bring more results based on that similarity. With all my heart I appreciate your time and feedback. We have recently added 103 search capability also. (just FYI) Also .......we chose to show 10 keeping individual inventors in mind so that they can decide whether to invest more money and time by knowing if the idea is new or not.Regarding the bug I shall share it with the team.

Comment: @AditiSyal Please see the update I made to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It may become useful as you develop it but right now is over-hyped on your ancillary materials. Blog, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your time George, totally understand. Yeah we are trying our best to improve it with time. As it's going to be open-source engine we look forward to collaborate with the finest minds on it.